# Facebook iFrame application javascript not running

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website/facebook application that is accessible at:

http://www.vibecompass.com/
&&
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Promethius/302783119739394?sk=app_236915563048749 (test facebook page for application)

My 'login' button appears on the normal website (inserted via javascript after determining if user is logged in or not) however this does not work on the facebook iframe. Can anyone give me some tips on what might be happening? Thanks!

---

Edit 1:

Seems to be related to an issue with facebook's all.js:
"d.onload is not a function"

This is preventing the getLoginStatus callback from firing. I'm asynchronously loading the facebook js sdk.

Comment: Post your javascript code here.